# SOAP request on Azure VM returns empty result immediately

Tags: azure, soap

I have an IIS, on an azure VM, that host a web application that I use to retrive data through SOAP request. Everything works fine if I access from localhost but as soon as I access to some functions from outside I get a response formally correct but with no data in it.

Configuring different VM with the same services I had the same results. I changed `<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="1024000" />` because it seems the problem was related to the amount of data retrived but I had no positive result. It isn't a timeout problem because other functions return values even after 30 seconds.

Is there anything else I might I have done wrong, or that I need to configure to allow SOAP requests from my Azure web application? Where can I look for better diagnostics to see what's going wrong?

Comment: What does Fiddler show in the response header & body?

Comment: Nathan I found the solution changing perspective. It was not a problem due to web site configuration but related to application code. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Configuring on the target VM a development environment I discovered the problem was releted to the differences of Culture set on sever and on Client.
This caused a transformation of parameters sent to sql server for data extraction.
I had to change the code to become Culture invariant.